# Change the NewPage for a TcxPageControl in the PageChanging event

Tags: devexpress, vcl, pagecontrol

We use a page control to step through a selection process from orders to products. The first tab shows a list of orders, the second tab shows a list of products for the selected order, and the 3rd tab contains a list of properties for the selected product.

If the user choose an order with only 1 product, we want to skip tab 2 and go straight to tab 3 to show the properties of the sole product.

I thought this could be done by setting the NewPage property of the PageChanging event, but it doesn't. What is a better way? To set the ActivePageIndex within the PageChanging event instead?

Answer (score 0):

I would hide the tabs so the user cannot select them at all, and then use a pair of buttons to move back and forth between the pages as needed.  When the user is on page 1 and is ready to move to the next page, the button handler can decide which page to show next.